# Selectbox option stay selected after page refresh jsp

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

I have a jsp page with simple `select` html element. Atm, when i select one of options and click `Wyswietl` button, page refresh, table data is refreshing, however selected option resets do default... How to force it to stay selected after page refresh?

I found a script from another topic on stackoverflow however it is not working for me.

my JSP page with script added:

```
<%@page import="java.util.*,tim.lab1.model.Uczen"%>
<%@page import="java.util.*,tim.lab1.model.Klasa"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Gradebook</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet"
href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">    </script>
<script
src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.js">  </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    var name = "Currency=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i].trim();
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0)
            $('#uczniowieKlasy').val(c.substring(name.length, c.length));
    }
});

$('#uczniowieKlasy').change(function(e) {
    var cookieVal = "Currency=" + $(this).val();
    document.cookie = cookieVal;

});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>Gradebook</h1>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
        <li role="presentation"><a href="klasaPage">Zarzadzaj
                klasami</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="przedmiotPage">Zarzadzaj
                przedmiotami</a></li>
        <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="uczenPage">Zarzadzaj
                uczniami</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="ocenaPage">Zarzadzaj
                ocenami</a></li>
    </ul>
    <br> <b>Dodaj ucznia:</b>
    <form method="POST" action="uczenPage">
        Imie: <input type="text" name="imie" /> Nazwisko: <input type="text"
            name="nazwisko" /> Klasa: <select name="idKlasa">
            <%
                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                List<Klasa> klasy = (List<Klasa>) request.getAttribute("klasy");
                if (klasy != null) {
                    for (Klasa k : klasy) {
            %>
            <option value="<%=k.getId()%>"><%=k.getId()%></option>
            <%
                }
                }
            %>
        </select> <input type="submit" name="action" value="Dodaj" />
    </form>
    <br> <b>Usun ucznia:</b>
    <form method="POST" action="uczenPage">
        ID: <input type="text" name="idToRemove" /> <input type="submit"
            name="action" value="Usun" />
    </form>
    <br>
    <hr>
    Uczniowie klasy:

    <form method="GET" action="uczenPage">
        <select name="uczniowieKlasy">
            <option value="wszystkie">Wszystkie</option>
            <%
                if (klasy != null) {
                    for (Klasa k : klasy) {
            %>
            <option value="<%=k.getId()%>"><%=k.getId()%></option>
            <%
                }
                }
            %>
        </select> <input type="submit" name="action" value="Wyswietl" />
    </form>
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Imie</th>
            <th>Nazwisko</th>
            <th>ID klasy</th>
        </tr>
        <%
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            List<Uczen> uczniowie = (List<Uczen>) request
                    .getAttribute("uczniowie");
            if (uczniowie != null) {
                for (Uczen u : uczniowie) {
        %>
        <tr>
            <td><%=u.getId()%></td>
            <td><%=u.getImie()%></td>
            <td><%=u.getNazwisko()%></td>
            <td><%=u.getKlasa().getId()%></td>
        </tr>
        <%
            }
            }
        %>
    </table>
    <hr>
</div>
```

What if i will have more selectboxes and want to remember all of their selected options?

**EDIT**

What if I want to use this script in multiple jsp page? Where i need to save a .js file to make it visible for .jsp pages?

This is my project structure:

```
src
---- main
--------- java
--------- resources
--------- webapp
-------------------META-INF
-------------------WEB-INF
-------------------all of my JSP pages
```

Comment: You must include the `js` in `head.jsp` which must be included in all JSPs :)

Comment: cant i add directly a `js` file in header of `jsp` files some way? like: 
`<script src="my.js"></script>`. But where i need to put JS file then, to be visible for JSP

Comment: In your resources folder. Remember to put entry for resources url mapping in your spring config

Comment: what if im not using spring ?

Comment: Mostly all static files will be in resources folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/wafali/1/edit?html,js,console,output)**

You can use localStorage to achieve that purpose as well. Each time the select option is changed store that in localStorage and when the page loads update it again.

This approach is for multiple select options in the same page

> HTML:

```
<body>
  <select name="uczniowieKlasy">
      <option value="wszystkie">Wszystkie</option>
      <option value="sdfsdf">sdfsf</option>
      <option value="fdfs">sdfs657f</option>
  </select>
    <select name="sdfsdfsf">
      <option value="wszystkie">Wszystkie</option>
      <option value="sdfsdf">sdfsf</option>
      <option value="fdfs">323</option>
  </select>
   <select name="sdfsf">
      <option value="gsdsf">Wszystkie</option>
      <option value="sdfsdf">sdfsf</option>
      <option value="fdfs">456456</option>
  </select>
</body>
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
   var selectOptions;
   if(localStorage.getItem("selectOptions")) {
       selectOptions = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("selectOptions"));
       Object.keys(selectOptions).forEach(function(select) {
         $("select[name="+select+"]").val(selectOptions[select]);
       });
  } else {
     selectOptions = {};
  }
  $("select").change(function() {
       var $this =  $(this),
           selectName = $this.attr("name");
      selectOptions[selectName] = $this.val();
      localStorage.setItem("selectOptions", JSON.stringify(selectOptions));
    });

});
```

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly, can u check my question in update of this topic too?